# Как лучше сделать взаимодействие Service и самого приложения с БД SQlite

Tags: android, java, service

У меня есть некое приложение, при взаимодействии с которым пользователь может добавлять данные в БД. Также есть сервис, который должен быть постоянно включен и периодически проверять эту БД и выполнять некие действия с данными,а потом удалять ненужные записи из БД. В БД хранится некая инфа,а также дата, когда эта инфа должна быть обработана сервисом.

Далее поясню,как я реализовал эту мысль. В принципе работает как хотел, но есть некоторые проблемы с взаимодействием БД, т.к. сервис и само приложение могут ссылаться на него в любой момент времени и, если они будут это делать одновременно, то я получаю ошибки разного рода,но в основном они касаются того, что БД уже открыта или **cursor**, который я получаю из БД кидает ошибку **NullPointerException**.

Расскажу вкратце, как всё это нечто работает: При включении телефона сервис включается автоматически, проверяет БД на актуальность дат,если даты устаревшие,то удаляет записи с такими датами (Такую проверку он будет производить каждые пол часа,для этого я использовал **Timer** и выделил под него соответствующий **TimerTask** с кодом проверки),тут, вроде как проблем не было. Далее сервис берёт актуальные данные и создаёт под каждые данные свой **Timer**, который сработает по дате из БД (У каждой записи своя дата), далее,когда **Timer** сработал, сервис удаляет запись из БД.

Приложение работает так: Мы добавляем некие данные в БД, можем их снова просмотреть, изменить или удалить. При добавлении новых данных, изменении или удалении сервис должен обновиться и создать новые **Timer** с уже новыми данными. Вот тут есть маленькая проблемка: чтобы обновить сервис, я вызываю команду **startservice()**, сервис заново не создаётся, оно и понятно, т.к. вызовы **startservice()** при включенном сервисе вызовут только команду **OnStartCommand()**, там я останавливаю предыдущий сервис командой **stopSelf()** и создаю новые **Timer** с данными. Здесь я тоже получаю ошибку, когда обновляю из приложения данные в БД, как я уже писал выше, сервис тоже должен обновиться, в последствии всего этого я получаю ошибку, потому что старые **Timer** объекты не были удалены в месте с предыдущим сервисом. Вот тут у меня возникает ещё 1 вопрос, если **Timer** объекты не удаляются вместе с остановкой сервиса,в котором они были созданы,то мне их явно надо остановить? Если да, то какой командой? **sleep()**?

Прошу вас помочь советом, т.к. разобраться надо в любом случае, решить проблему с синхронным подключением к БД сервисом и приложением хотел с помощью глобальных переменных (Если кто-то подключается к базе,то указывал в ней **true**, а когда закрывал базу,устанавливал в **false**, а все остальные, кто пытается прочитать БД  прокручивают бесконечный цикл и проверяют переменную на **false**, далее выполняют **такуюже** операцию с глобальной переменной)

Comment: Забыл дописать, stopSelf() я использовал с параметром id сервиса  stopSelf(int id)

Answer (score 7):

У вас походу полная каша в голове - представляю какая каша в коде...

Любая БД умеет правильно распорядиться с синхронным доступом к ней, на то есть механизм транзакций и проч.

1. Есть понятие `SQLiteOpenHelper`, которому можно возложить доступ к БД. Он при необходимости будет открывать БД или создавать.
2. Как кто-то уже предлагал в комментариях можно доступ к БД организовать через `ContentProvider` - это как бы самый правильный - андроидовский путь

В обоих способах, я бы лично рекомендовал использовать транзакции - проще говоря, обложить запросы вставки/обновления:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
  //blah-blah
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();     
  } finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Это обеспечит [надлежащую изоляцию данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%F0%EE%E2%E5%ED%FC_%E8%E7%EE%EB%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%ED%EE%F1%F2%E8_%F2%F0%E0%ED%E7%E0%EA%F6%E8%E9)

Comment: в blah-blah я должен подключится к БД и достать от туда данные или изменить их,если мне надо?

Comment: Прошу вас ответить,ибо я так вас понял

Comment: на момент blah-blah БД уже должны быть открыта. Открывают БД 1 раз при запуске аппы/активити/сервиса и закрывают тоже один раз при смерти аппы/активити/сервиса. Стартуют транзакцию перед вставкой или обновлением.

Comment: Ага,я понимаю так. Когда я открыл приложение, я 1 раз выполняю код: 

MyDBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper_UserIvents(this);


А потом я могу в любой момент выполнить:

SQLiteDatabase db_sqlite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); для получения cursor, или обновить БД методом insert() или удалить запись методом delete();

А по завершении сервиса закрыть БД методом close()

Я правильно понял? Если что неправильно написал,прошу сильно на меня не злиться и поправить, ибо мне до вас далеко

Comment: Да, примерно так. Только не забывайте про транзакции - поскольку у вас изменения в БД вносятся в сервисе и юзером. Так что, чтобы избежать ненужных коллизий примените транзакции. И почитайте про [ACID](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Comment: Спасибо вам,вы просто мой герой. Я её не так много знаю,всего полтора года java изучаю и андроид пол года, сам технарь приборостроитель по образованию, программирую для себя, никаких курсов не проходил,всё,что знаю, это из книжек или сайтов,по этому к грамотному коддингу ещё не приучен (если что-то работает,то работает, и ничего не трогать :)) ),понимаю,что так толькое что-то не напишешь,но я совершенствуюсь,и благодаря вам я узнал много чего нового.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK в форуме принято благодарить не словами типа 

>Спасибо вам,вы просто мой герой

а отметкой, ответ нравится/не нравится (с левой стороны от ответа). И если ответ принят, нужно отметить галочку (слева - снизу).

Comment: я кстати официальный герой как минимум 1-2х человек, один из них коллега, сказал что-то типа, "If you will able to fix it,  you will be my officiall superhero" на тот момент он два дня уже тыкался, через 5 мин я написал ему fixed :)